# Follow the path of sb

Tags: prepositions

Can I use the expression "follow the path" + of with a person? e.g. Follow the path of the old master. Or would it sound better: Walk the path of the old master?

It should be the title of an article about China and the thoughts of Lao Zi and the meaning I want to convey - exploring China following the paths of the old master (his path and thoughts)

Answer (score 1):

You could use either option, with a slight distinction in meaning where walking the path is more active than following the path. Depending on your article this might me relevant, if it's an analysis of his philosophy, then following would be more suitable. If it is you reinterpreting his philosophy in a new/current context, I'd use walking.

Comment: Thanks very much. Very helpful.